# 'abs': ambiguous call to overloaded function: исход компиляции многих Direct3D примеров

Tags: c++, directx

Здравствуйте. При компиляции некоторых примеров из MS DirectX SDK (June 2010) происходит `..\..\DXUT\Core\DXUTenum.cpp(3976): error С2668: 'abs': ambiguous call to overloaded function`. Text3D в папке "Samples\C++\Direct3D\" напрочь отказывается компилировать. Компилятор: VC++14 Update 3.

Англ источники в решении проблемы особо-то и не помогли. Что с этим делать, пока ума не могу приложить. Соответственно, влезть в строку 3976 я не могу т.к. после редактировании любого инклюда с DXUT студия выдает ошибку при линковке. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным при работе с новыми компиляторами и D3D9? Что с этим делать?

DirectX SDK скачал из официального сайта. Ссылку искать не буду, да и не вспомню, ибо давно. Собираю под Win32/Debug mode, исходник, как и другие ресурсы в семплах оригинальный. Если запущу свой старенький комп с AMD процессором, на нем есть VS2010 и тот SDK, постараюсь построить проект там.

Comment: VC++14 это VS2015? На других версиях собирается? Добавьте в вопрос ссылки, откуда Вы качали SDK. И опишите подробнее как пытаетесь собрать.

Comment: Да - VS2015, за другие не знаю. Компилятор менять из-за такой мелочи не хотелось бы.

Comment: В VS2010 все собирается без единой ошибки.